# C++: std::merge => using for sorted lists

Tags: c++, sorting, merge

I got two sorted lists. They are sorted like this, after a function (sort_func), which I defined:

```
std::sort(list1.begin(), list1.end(), sort_func());
```

Now I want to merge these two lists. That should be easy and efficient, because they are both already sorted the same way.

If I use `std::merge`, does it take the advantage of the already sorted lists? Or should I write my own merge function instead to be faster?

I do this at the moment:

```
std::merge(list1.begin(), list1.end(), list2.begin(), list2.end(), std::back_inserter(list), sort_func());
```

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A precondition of using `std::merge` is that both lists are already sorted. So yes, it takes advantage of this.

> Merges two sorted ranges [first1, last1) and [first2, last2) into one sorted range beginning at d_first.

Answer (score 1):

[std::merge](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) requires that the two input lists be sorted, so it does take advantage of this. There is no need to build your own.

From the standard (N3242 §25.4.4.2):

> Requires: The ranges [first1,last1) and [first2,last2) shall be sorted with respect to operator<
>   or comp. The resulting range shall not overlap with either of the original ranges.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the standard container `std::list` has member functions `merge` that accept a comparison function object. They are

```
template <class Compare> 
void merge(list& x, Compare comp); 
template <class Compare> 
void merge(list&& x, Compare comp);
```

So you can use them.

Thus you have a choice either to use the standard algorithm std::merge or to use these member functions of the std::list.

Take into account that you should use the same comparison function `sort_func()` that was used to sort the lists if you want that the result list would be also ordered according to this function.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the task can be done using only native methods of the class `std::list`. Instead of your comparison function there is used function object `std::greater` declared in header `<functional>`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <functional>

int main() 
{
    std::list<int> list1 = { 3, 1, 5, 9, 7 };
    std::list<int> list2 = { 8, 0, 4, 6, 2 };

    list1.sort( std::greater<int>() );
    list2.sort( std::greater<int>() );

    std::list<int> list( list1 );

    list.merge( list2, std::greater<int>() );

    for ( int x : list ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```